# The sum of four whole numbers is six. In how many ways can this be done, if none of the numbers is greater than three?

Tags: combinatorics

Note that the order of the numbers does NOT matter. For example, (0,2,2,2), (2,0,2,2), (2,2,0,2), and (2,2,2,0) will be taken as just one combination.
The correct answer is five. Of course, this can easily be found by 'trying' different values but I am looking for a more mathematical approach, so that I may apply the same logic for bigger numbers.

Comment: The buzzword here is "integer partition," see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts

Comment: This is also the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3)^4$, but that isn't necessarily easier to calculate (though there is a process, using the binomial theorem).

Comment: The coefficient of x^6 in (1+x+x^2+x^3)^4 comes out to be 44. This is because you're taking (0,2,2,2) as four different combinations, (1,2,3,4) as 24 different combinations, and so on. This is exactly what I need to avoid somehow, to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Idk how you say the correct answer is $5$. I get $9$ which can easily be 
enumerated.

$6-0-0-0$ [part$(6,1)$]
$5-1-0-0,\; 4-2-0-0,\; 3-3-0-0$ [part$(6,2)$] 
$4-1-1-0,\; 3-2-1-0,\; 2-2-2-0$ [part$(6,3)$]
$3-1-1-1,\; 2-2-1-1$ [part$(6,4)$]

As already commented, this deals with partitions, distributing indistinguishable objects to indistinguishable boxes, about which you can read more [here](http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/CountingObjectsInBoxes.aspx) and find recursion formulas.

Comment: I forgot to mention the 'none of the numbers is greater than three' condition. Extremely sorry for that. I have now edited the question to what I actually intended it to be, and NOW the correct answer is five.

Comment: ok, 5 is correct for your edited question. Have a look at http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.9 and other sites on partitions.